# If $X > 1$ is odd, what is the negation of "$X$ is divisible by at least two distinct odd primes"?

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Let $X > 1$ be odd.

My present question is pretty basic:

> What is the (logically correct) negation of the following number-theoretic proposition?
>
> > $\mathscr{X} := $"$X$ is divisible by at least two distinct odd primes."

**MY ATTEMPT**

(I am not sure if what follows is called *first-order logic*, but oh well.)

Let $p, q$ be primes.  Then is the negation of $\mathscr{X}$ the same as

> $\lnot\mathscr{X} = $"$X$ is divisible by exactly one odd prime."?

I doubt the validity of my answer, because it cannot be that simple.

Comment: I am not quite sure myself. I think it should be: "A natural number $X$ is not divisible by at least two distinct odd primes." $\iff$ "A natural number $X$ is divisible by one or none odd prime." Edit: I see, that $X$ is odd. In that case only one odd prime divides $X$ as $2$ never divides an odd number. So, your answer seems right to me.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @FlynnFehre!  Following your logic, and using the fact that $X > 1$ is odd, then I am getting $\lnot\mathscr{X} = $"A natural number $X$ is divisible by exactly one odd prime."

Comment: The original statement is something like: $\forall n \exists x \exists y [OP(x) \land OP(y) \land (x \ne y) \to (x|n \land y|n)]$

Comment: If so, the negation will be: $\exists n \forall x \forall y \ \lnot [OP(x)∧OP(y)∧(x≠y)→(x|n∧y|n)]$. Now we have to "move inside" the negation sign taking into account the logical equiv: $\lnot (P \to Q)$ and $(P \land \lnot Q)$.

Comment: So is Freshman's Dream's answer correct, @MauroALLEGRANZA?  Thank you for your time and attention. =)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @ryang!  Omitting "**A natural number**" from the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a natural number doesn't need to have an odd divisor, and either $\mathscr{X}$ or $\lnot \mathscr{X}$ must be true. For example if $X=4$, none of the two is correct  the way you wrote it.

$\lnot\mathscr{X} = $"A natural number $X$ is divisible by **at most** one odd prime." should be correct.

Edit: I just saw that $X$ is odd. Your answer is correct in that case.